# Pay a user with Paypal

Tags: paypal

I want to use Paypal to pay users with a paypal button.

I tried to use a standard cmd=_xclick, but it doesn't return enough informations after processing the payment. IPN seems to concentrate on stores and not on payrolls, and Mass Pay seems incomplete (it needs an xml list of users informations at start, and there is no real-time modification of users informations).

Is there only Mass Pay api that is reliable for payment?

I really thought I could solve this one using google, but none of the threads and documentations really solved my problem.

[Edit]

I tried MassPay but didn't qualify with only a Premier Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Adaptive Payments -> Implicit Payments.

It allows you to programatically send money out of your own paypal account.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro

(You have to scroll down a bit until you find Implicit Payment Flow)

Comment: I finally figured out I should use implicit payments for a [my-account]->[another person] flow. So this is the answer. Works really well out of the box. Sadly, I need X.com to approve my application and they don't give any clue about how many time it takes. This is the paypal mentality.

Comment: In my experience, for a simple application like this you're probably looking at about 3~4 business days. Make sure you only select the permissions you require.  If you go crazy and select everything in the form, it's going to delay the approval a lot.

Comment: Well, maybe I choosed 3 permissions and only needed 2 permissions. The problem is that they have a very minimalist approach about options/revisions. So, you can't: 1. Revise your application request without deleting it. 2. You can't even see which options you choosed. I hope it will only take 3-4 days.